# Keeping database table in sync with REST API response

Tags: python, json, postgresql, rest

I have a REST API that returns a large array of JSON objects like this

```
[
    {
        "company": "3M",
        "description": "3M, based in Minnesota,...",
        "initial_price": 44.28,
        "price_2002": 56.27,
        "price_2007": 95.85,
        "symbol": "MMM"
    },
    {
        "company": "Amazon.com",
        "description": "Amazon.com, Inc. ...",
        "initial_price": 89.38,
        "price_2002": 17.01,
        "price_2007": 93.43,
        "symbol": "AMZN"
    },
    {
        "company": "Campbell Soup",
        "description": "Campbell Soup is a ...",
        "initial_price": 37.0,
        "price_2002": 22.27,
        "price_2007": 36.4,
        "symbol": "CPB"
    },
    ...
]
```

I want to keep this data in sync with a postgres/sqlite3 database using a python SQLAlchemy app that runs every day. By in-sync, I mean any new data(inserts), changes in value(updates) and deletes in the API response should be reflected in the database table.

What is the most efficient way to approach this problem?

Comment: Do you own the api ? how do you insert/update data in dbs ?

Comment: No, It's an external API. I want to sync it to a local database to access this data offline, refreshed everyday.

Comment: id say to make a script with [schedule package](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) with a function or use a your desktop cron service with python script to fetch api data, and insert / update rows in sql in your local db

Comment: How do I manage deletes? efficiently?

Comment: depends on what you want to delete, you can use sql with 'DELETE FROM table WHERE company='name' and etc ...'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for trading, then I would do event sourcing and save the changes in an event queue. Something like

```
[
{"symbol": "MMM", "price": 44.28, "timestamp": "...", "type": "PriceChange"},
{"symbol": "MMM", "price": 48.65, "timestamp": "...", "type": "PriceChange"},
{"symbol": "MMM", "price": 42.34, "timestamp": "...", "type": "PriceChange"},
...
]
```

Whenever a new event is added you can update your query database. Later you can use the historical data with a different query database to have better predictions about the price change.